# setting fonts for button in android, throw exception app has stopped

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to set custom font for my widgets, In my app. I used the following code for that:

```
Context context = getBaseContext();
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/tahoma.ttf");
Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
bt.setTypeface(font);
```

But when I run my program, the emulator shows "**Unfortunately, firstTest has stopped**".